Query to concatenate row data in each group
I have following records:
Date            Id      Ethnicity   Gender      Age 
-----------------------------------------------------
2021-03-25      001     NULL        NULL        39
2021-03-25      001     Hispanic    Male        39
2022-02-01      002     NULL        NULL        NULL
2022-02-01      002     Unknown     Male        27
2022-02-01      002     Hispanic    Male        27
2022-02-01      002     NULL        Male        NULL
2022-02-02      003     NULL        Male        Null
2022-02-02      003     White       Male        Null

I want to write a SQL query in SQL Server to concatenate the Ethnicity, Gender and Age for each Date and ID group
2021-03-25          001     Hispanic, Male, 39
2022-02-01          002     Hispanic, Male, 27
2022-02-02          003     White, Male

Thanks in advance!
I tried to used STRING_AGG() to concatenate these columns, but the data is duplicated such as for ID 002, I got "Unknown, Male, 27, Hispanic, Male,27, Male"

Something like this perhaps?
SELECT  CONCAT_WS(', ', MAX(NULLIF(Ethnicity, 'Unknown')), MAX(NULLIF(gender, 'Unknown')), MAX(NULLIF(age, 'Unknown')))
,   Date, ID
FROM    (
    VALUES  (N'2021-03-25', N'001', NULL, NULL, 39)
    ,   (N'2021-03-25', N'001', N'Hispanic', N'Male', 39)
    ,   (N'2022-02-01', N'002', NULL, NULL, NULL)
    ,   (N'2022-02-01', N'002', N'Unknown', N'Male', 27)
    ,   (N'2022-02-01', N'002', N'Hispanic', N'Male', 27)
    ,   (N'2022-02-01', N'002', NULL, N'Male', NULL)
    ,   (N'2022-02-02', N'003', NULL, N'Male', NULL)
    ,   (N'2022-02-02', N'003', N'White', N'Male', NULL)
) t (Date,Id,Ethnicity,Gender,Age)
GROUP BY date,id

This groups the dates and takes the maximum of each value while filtering out unknowns /nulls. Of course, it there are several non-null values, this might return incorrect numbers, but then you need to update the question with more details.
If you don't have CONCAT_WS, you can use CONCAT with similar effect.

SELECT 
    Date, Id, 
    STRING_AGG(Ethnicity, ', ') AS EthnicityGenderAge
FROM
    YourTableName
WHERE 
    Ethnicity IS NOT NULL
    AND Gender IS NOT NULL
    AND Age IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY 
    Date, Id;


But that really doesn't concatenate the Ethnicity, Gender and Age columns into a new, single column .....

Cant set condition     Ethnicity IS NOT NULL AND Gender IS NOT NULL AND Age IS NOT NULLin Where clause. If Ethnicity is null in the column within the group I still need concatenating Gender and Age if they are not null.
